# Theme in MaterialApp not working in widgets Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

This is my code, I have the theme defined clearly as shown below.
But, the color of the container in the `home` is still coming up to be blue in Chrome browser.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Spotify UI',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.black),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF121212),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF121212),
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        accentColor: const Color(0xFF1DB954),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData().copyWith(color: Colors.white),
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline2: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 32.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          headline4: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            letterSpacing: 2.0,
          ),
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
          ),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the color of your `Container` widget is taken from `context`, which is an argument of the `build` method of `MyApp`.

`MaterialApp` has a theme, but `MyApp` doesn't have a theme. So when you use the `context` of `MyApp` to get the primary color, that context doesn't have any theme yet and you get the default primary color.

Instead, what you can do is:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Spotify UI',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        // ...
      ),
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that there was already an answer. That answer is very good too.

Comment: This led to an 'invalid constant value' build error for me, which was slightly confusing since it's due to the parent Widget being declared a 'const'. Removing const on the parent widget fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MaterialApp`s body yet does not contain updated `BuildContext` with themes in its body.
Wrap your `Column` with `Builder` to provide updated context:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Spotify UI',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.black),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF121212),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF121212),
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        accentColor: const Color(0xFF1DB954),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData().copyWith(color: Colors.white),
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline2: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 32.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          headline4: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            letterSpacing: 2.0,
          ),
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
          ),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: Builder( // <- Here
        builder: (context) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this also solves the problem. Interesting approach!